# Close plot window without clear figure object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a figure in python with matplotlib , the problem is that I need to store figure object , if i close the plot window (that I get with `plt.show()` ). Infact if after `plt.show()` , I close the window's figure I also loose the figure object. Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Use the object oriented API. e.g., your entry point can be `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`.

Comment: Please can you provide me an example?

Comment: Try saving the plot in memory using io and plot.savefig.

Comment: Can you please post some code demonstrating what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: `plt.figure(1); plt.plot(x,y); plt.show();` now when close the window after that i invoke show() , I loose the figure that I've plotted